# DateTime format in python from Postgres queries

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a below result from postgres query performing in python.

```
(datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 22, 15, 18, 17, 677821, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)),)
```

How can parse or format so I get date along with time only ?

Comment: You are getting the date and the time. You will need to provide an example of the sort of output you want to end up with. Add as update to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by using result[0][0] in pyhton code